# laravel multiple join conditions with integer values

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I want to make a join with multiple conditions:

```
->join('filters', function($join) {
    $join->on('filters.result_id', '=', 'results.id');
    $join->on('filters.result_filter_id', '=', 2);
    $join->on('filters.value', '>', 1);
})
```

This results in an error:

> Unknown column '2' in 'on clause'

How can I use actual values in the join on condition without having eloquent interpret it as a column name? It works fine with the actual SQL query:

```
JOIN filters ON filters.result_id = results.id 
AND filters.result_filter_id = 2 
AND filters.value > 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `on` with `where` if you want to filter your join

> If you would like to use a "where" style clause on your joins, you may use the where and orWhere methods on a join

```
->join('filters', function($join) {
    $join->on('filters.result_id', '=', 'results.id')
        ->where('filters.result_filter_id', '=', 2)
        ->where('filters.value', '>', 1);
})
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins)